# Why Can't I get props data in vue.js?

Tags: vuejs3

I provided subcomponent with parent component'props.
but it didn't get them.

Below is the main code. I will tell you the process.

1. When you click on an element in the IndicatorListSelectOne component, the clicked element information is transmitted to the parent node and to the same level component called SetIndicatorParameter.
2. After modifying some of the transmitted information in the SetIndicatorParameter component, the information is saved and the information is transmitted again to the parent component.
3. The transmitted information is finally transmitted to UsableIndicators, a component at the same level. But here's where the problem arises. The previously initialized baseVarsList is passed on as is, but the remaining three continuously updated variables are not updated at all and are passed as empty values ​​even though they are passed as props. What's the problem?

parent component

```
<template>
...
<div class="row gy-4">
  <IndicatorListSelectOne v-model="selectedIndicator"></IndicatorListSelectOne>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-8">
    <div class="row gy-4">
    <SetIndicatorParameter
      :selected-indicator="selectedIndicator"
      @update-variables="updateVariables"/>
    <UsableIndicators
      :created-vars="createdVars"
      :created-vars-name-list="createdVarsNameList"
      :created-vars-name-dict="createdVarsNameDict"
      :base-vars-list="baseVarsList"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
</template>
<script>
...
data() {
  return {
    baseVarsList: {
                "a": "b",
                "c": "d",...
            },
    selectedIndicator: "",
    createdVars: [],
    createdVarsNameList: [],
    createdVarsNameDict: {},
  }
},
...

methods: {
...
updateVariables(data) {
            this.createdVarsNameList = data.createdVarsNameList;
            this.createdVarsNameDict = data.createdVarsNameDict;
            this.createdVars = data.createdVars;
            console.log(this.createdVars)
            console.log(this.createdVarsNameList)
            console.log(this.createdVarsNameDict)
        },
},
...
</script>
```

SetIndicatorParameter.vue

```
method: {
...
this.$emit('update-variables', {
                    createdVarsNameList: this.varsNameList,
                    createdVarsNameDict: this.addedVariableDict,
                    createdVars: this.vars
                });
...
}
```

When a specific button is pressed on the component, the code below is executed and three variables are sent to the parent component.

UsableIndicators.vue

```
<template>
  <label>...</label>
  <div class="variable-list-container">
    <div class="checkbox-card" v-for="(value, key) in baseVarsList" :key="key">
      <input :id="'default'+key" type="checkbox" :value="'default'+key"/>
      <label :for="'default'+key">{{ key }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
  <label>...</label>
  <div class="variable-list-container"> 
    <div v-for="(value, index) in createdVarsNameList" :key="index" class="checkbox-card">
      <input :id="'generated'+index" type="checkbox" :value="'generated'+index"/>
      <label :for="'generated'+index" class="justify-content-between">{{ value }}
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i data-feather="x"
      color="#AAA"></i></a>
      </label>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
props: {
  createdVars: Array,
  createdVarsNameList: Array,
  createdVarsNameDict: Object,
  baseVarsList: Object,
}
</script>
```

At this time, nothing appears in createdVrasNameList.

I checked it through the console and confirmed that the information is delivered to the parent component, but the information is not delivered to the child component.

what's the problems?

Comment: it doesn't look like you have any of your props actually binding, see the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind).  All `selected-indicator="selectedIndicator"` does is set the prop value for selected-indicator to be the **string literal value** `"selectedIndicator"`.  To bind the **variable** you have to bind with v-bind or the short-hand `:`, e.g. `:selected-indicator="selectedIndicator"`

Comment: Also, if you're emitting from a component, you then have to listen and respond in the parent, which you don't do.  Again, see the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-handling).  If you emit event `'update-variables'` in child, parent needs to listen on that component with `<SetIndicatorParameter @update-variables="someMethod">`.

Comment: @yoduh oops! all of them you said are done in my code. Its my fault not to write above code. : and @ are written.